# how to form array of arrays from object array in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Am trying form data from object array to array of arrays in JavaScript but am unable to get the result

> Input Data { "sept" : [1,2,3], "oct" : [5,6,7] "Nov" : [7,8,9]}
>
> Expected Output [["sept",1,2,3],["oct",5,6,7],["Nov",7,8,9]]

I have tried a lot I can able to get the keys by `Object.Key()` but can able to form the data with the value as expected output above, please help me to resolve this Thanks in advance

Comment: "*I have tried a lot*" Can you share the code for those attempts, along with an explanation for each as to why the attempt didn't meet your requirements? The community may be able to more effectively help you by seeing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the entries and map key and values in an array.

```js
const 
    data = { sept: [1, 2, 3], oct: [5, 6, 7], Nov: [7, 8, 9] },
    result = Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k, ...v]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over properties using `for .. in` loop, you will get the result.

```js
const obj = {
  "sept": [1, 2, 3],
  "oct": [5, 6, 7],
  "Nov": [7, 8, 9],
}

const result = [];

for (const prop in obj) {
  result.push([prop, ...obj[prop]]);
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.entries()` and then `.map()` with `...` - rest/spread operator

```js
const object = {
  september: [1, 2, 3],
  october: [5, 6, 7],
  november: [7, 8, 9],
}

const result = Object.entries(object).map(([key, value])=>[key, ...value])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.entries` then spread the values along with the key

```js
const data = { sept: [1, 2, 3], oct: [5, 6, 7], Nov: [7, 8, 9] }

const res = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => [key, ...value])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ramda.js library has a function that does exactly this called `toPairs()`

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs